# How would you solve an equation of the form $e^{-x} - \sin(x) = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've been trying to do this for ages. I'm worried that it's impossible, but I have heard that it can be done by hand.

As long as I can get $x$ by hand I can obviously work out its value via calculator.

Please help, I am so stuck and desperately need assistance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Graph the two functions $e^{-x}$ and $\sin(x)$ and find where they intersect (approximately).

Comment: I should add that I'm looking for an algebraic method if possible!

Comment: I'd be shocked if it's doable since [Wolfram can only offer approximations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-x%29+%3D+sin%28x%29). Not that "proof by Wolfram" is a thing, just a heuristic.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer interestingly, [with a mild interpretation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-pi*x%29+%3D+sin%28pi*x%29), these are close enough to analytic answers. Not sure about the first two solutions yet, but the others clearly look like $n\pi$ for all integer $n \ge 2$.

Comment: If you replace sin by sinh then it can be done by hand. I get x = 1/2 \ln 3 in that case.

Comment: @gt6989b Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3602833/347062)

Comment: A question that’s probably more feasible than finding exact solutions to this equation: given a few solutions as constants, can we construct more solutions to the equation in terms of those solutions?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, that equation is highly nonlinear, as a result analytically we may not (can not) find a solution.

**First Observation:** Note that when $x$ becomes very large $e^{-x}$ becomes very small so $$e^{-x}-\sin x\approx0-\sin x$$ and hence the zeros of $\sin x$ are the zeros of $e^{-x}-\sin x$. This observation also ensures that **solution for $e^{-x}-\sin x=0$ exists**.

**Second Observation:** For $x<0$ $e^{-x}$ is an increasing function and dominates $\sin x$ (Which can be seen in the graph too) so there are no zeros of the function $e^{-x}-\sin x$ for $x<0$.

**So what's the solution?** Well, the solution can only be found by Numerical methods. One easy way to do that by plotting graphs.

[image: graph 1]

This is the graph of $e^{-x}-\sin x$ where the first observation is visualized.

[image: graph 2]

This is the graph showing the intersection of $e^{-x}$ [Blue line] and $\sin x$ [Red line].

In one word the solutions are $x=0.589,3.096,6.285$ etc.

Hope this works.

Comment: Would there be a way to show that over any interval before the first solution the function as a whole is increasing?

Comment: You mean decreasing right? So you wanna show that $e^{-x}-\sin x$ is decreasing in $(\infty,0]$?

Comment: Close. I want to show that it's decreasing over (-infinity, 0.589)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot find a closed form for the zeroes, but you can find asymptotic approximations.

Let $x_n$ be the zero in $(\pi n-\frac \pi 2, \pi n+\frac \pi 2)$. Write $x_n=\pi n+\varepsilon_n$ with $|\varepsilon_n|<\frac \pi 2$.

Then $$e^{-\pi n -\varepsilon_n}=\sin(\pi n+\varepsilon_n)=(-1)^n\sin(\varepsilon_n)\tag{1}$$
Taking the limit, the left-hand-side converges to $0$. So this implies that $\varepsilon_n\rightarrow 0$. Thus, using Taylor expansions in $(1)$,
$$e^{-\pi n}(1+o(1))= (-1)^n \varepsilon_n(1 +o(1))$$
which means that
$$\varepsilon_n=(-1)^ne^{-\pi n}(1+o(1))$$

$$\boxed{x_n=\pi n+(-1)^n e^{-\pi n} + o(e^{-\pi n})}$$
The zeroes therefore converge exponentially fast towards multiples of $\pi$.

You can keep playing that game and plug the residual back into $(1)$ to find the next term in the expression of $x_n$, but this is already converging quite [fast](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5B%5Cpi*n%2B%28-1%29%5En*e%5E%28-%5Cpi+*+n%29%2C+20%5D+for+n%3D1...10).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you build the series expansion of the rhs of
$$y=e^{-x}-\sin(x)$$ around $x=n \pi$ and later series reversion forcing $y=0$, you obtain
$$x_n=n\pi+\frac{1}{1+e^{(1+i) \pi  n}}+\frac{1}{2 \left(1+e^{(1+i) \pi  n}\right)^3}+\cdots$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 0.5625000000000000000 &  0.5885327439818610774 \\
 1 & 3.0963808805403588820 &  3.0963639324106461156 \\
 2 & 6.2850492723072431593 &  6.2850492733825865338 \\
 3 & 9.4246972547386088459 &  9.4246972547385212191 \\
 4 & 12.566374101689367670 &  12.566374101689367677 \\
 5 & 15.707963117247215942 &  15.707963117247215942 \\
 6 & 18.849555928051171524 &  18.849555928051171524 \\
 7 & 21.991148574847125823 &  21.991148574847125823 \\
 8 & 25.132741228730507464 &  25.132741228730507464 \\
 9 & 28.274333882307613598 &  28.274333882307613598 \\
 10 & 31.415926535897955096 &  31.415926535897955096
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Although there are already a few answers, all complex roots, except for $z=0.5885327\dots$ discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203313/solving-exp-x-sinx-analytically/4203506#4203506), have a simple explicit series expansion. For the real roots, substitute $w=e^{2iz}\iff z=\pi k-\frac i2\ln(w)$, apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem), and use [factorial power $n^{(m)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html): $$e^{-z}=\sin(z)\iff w=1+2ie^{(i-1)\pi k}w^\frac{1+i}2\implies z_k=\pi k-\frac i2\left(\ln(1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2 ie^{(i-1)\pi k})^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\ln’(w)w^{\frac{1+i}2n}\right|_1\right)=\pi k+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2i)^{n-1}(-e^{-\pi})^{ k n}}{n!}\left(\frac{1+i}2n-1\right)^{n-1}$$ There are two sets of complex roots which are conjugates of one another. To find them, substitute $u=e^{(1\pm i)z}\iff z=\frac{2\pi i k}{1\pm i}+\frac{\ln(w)}{1\pm i}$ and use Lagrange reversion: $$e^{-z}=\sin(z)\iff w=\pm2i+e^{2\pi k}w^{\pm i}\implies z_k=\frac{2\pi ik}{1\pm i}+\frac1{1\pm i}\left(\ln(\pm 2i)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{2\pi kn}}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\ln’(w)w^{\mp in}\right|_{\pm2i}\right)=\frac{1\pm i}4((4k\mp1)\pi i+2\ln(2))+(1\pm i)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\mp 2i)^{(-1\pm i)n}e^{2\pi k n}}{2n!}(\pm in-1)^{(n-1)}$$

For the real roots, $k\in\Bbb N$ and $\pm k\in\Bbb N$, for the complex roots, depends on whether all top/bottom signs are taken. The location of the $-z$ roots is [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/372939). Therefore:

$$\bbox[3px,border: darkturquoise 3px solid]{e^{-z}=\sin(z)\implies z_k= \pi k+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2i)^{n-1}(-e^{-\pi})^{ k n}}{n!}\left(\frac{1+i}2n-1\right)^{n-1},z_{\pm  k}= \pm\frac{1\pm i}4((4k-1)\pi i+2\ln(2))+(1\pm i)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\mp 2i)^{(-1\pm i)n}e^{\mp2\pi k n}}{2n!}(\pm in-1)^{(n-1)};k\in\Bbb N}$$

The real roots are [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FindRoot%5Bexp%28-z%29-sin%28z%29%2C%7Bz%2C%7B%CF%80%2C2%CF%80%2C3%CF%80%2C4%CF%80%7D%7D%5D%2CNumberForm%5B%CF%80+%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%7D%2Bsum%5B%282+i%29%5E%28n-1%29+%28-e+%5E-%CF%80%29%5E%28%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%7D+n%29%2Fn%21+factorialpower%28%281%2Bi%29%2F2+n-1%2Cn-1%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C50%7D%5D%2C13%5D), rounded matching @Claude Leibovici’s, and the complex roots are [shown here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/10452d98-2504-4ef0-9b5a-640ad44f02e7). If $n=0$, the series diverges so the [Fox Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) cannot easily be used. Also, if all of its parameters were extended to complex numbers and the $n=0$ problem were gone, then Fox Wright would give a closed form. Also, unless all parameters were extended into being complex, this function does give a closed form as well. It is of interest to find a similar expansion for $z_0= 0.5885327\dots$