# Proof that the roots of $\mathrm e^{-πx}=\sin πx$ approach integers as $x\to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, numerical-calculus

This question is inspired by [@gt6989b](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16192/gt6989b)’s comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3602747/347062).

Numerical analysis [suggests](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-pi*x%29%20%3D%20sin%28pi*x%29) that the roots of the equation $\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}} \e^{-πx} = \sin πx$ rapidly and closely approach integers as $x\to\infty$. Here’s a quick list of the first nine solutions:

$$\begin{array}{l}
0.18733579075230\dots \\
0.98560325090923\dots \\
2.00059331886993\dots \\
2.99997431047250\dots \\
4.00000111005168\dots \\
4.99999995203014\dots \\
6.00000000207297\dots \\
6.99999999991042\dots \\
8.00000000000387\dots \\
\end{array}$$

How can I prove (or disprove) that these values will get closer and closer to integers?

Wolfie notes that the system has the alternate form $$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}} \e^{-πx} = \frac{\i\e^{-\i πx} - \i\e^{\i πx}}2$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since for a large positive integer $n$, $e^{-\pi n} \approx 0$ and $\sin(\pi x)$ has roots at the integers, we expect that the equation has roots close to positive integers. To gain a better approximation, we choose the approximate value $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for the $n$th root $x_n$ and apply Newton's method once. This yields the better approximation:
$$
x_n  \approx n + \frac{1}{\pi }\frac{1}{{( - 1)^n e^{\pi n}  + 1}}.
$$
This shows that $x_n$ converges to $n$ exponentially fast.

Comment: Beautifully succinct! +25

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function
$$y= e^{\pi x}\,\sin(\pi x)$$ and expand it around $x=n$
$$y=(-1)^n e^{n \pi}\left(\pi  (x-n)+\pi ^2 (x-n)^2+\frac{1}{3} \pi ^3 (x-n)^3+O\left((x-n)^5\right)\right)$$ Now, use series reversion to get
$$x=n+\frac{e^{-n\pi} }{\pi }y\left(e^{-i \pi  n}-e^{(-1-2 i) \pi  n} y+\frac{5}{3} e^{(-2-3 i) \pi  n} y^2-\frac{10}{3}
   e^{(-3-4 i) \pi  n} y^3+O\left(y^4\right)\right)$$ and now, make $y=1$ to get
$$x_n=n+(-1)^n\frac{ e^{-n\pi  }}{\pi }-\frac{e^{-2n \pi }}{\pi }+(-1)^n\frac{5  e^{-3 n\pi  }}{3 \pi }-\frac{10 e^{-4 \pi  n}}{3 \pi }+\cdots$$

Using this truncated formula
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 1 & 0.985603644503601858348373 \\
 2 & 2.000593318869874358850040 \\
 3 & 2.999974310472503086561926 \\
 4 & 4.000001110051677367565600 \\
 5 & 4.999999952030143030217180 \\
 6 & 6.000000002072965152317527 \\
 7 & 6.999999999910419052735504 \\
 8 & 8.000000000003871143731943 \\
 9 & 8.999999999999832712711178 \\
 10 & 10.00000000000000722913923 \\
 11 & 10.99999999999999968760057 \\
 12 & 12.00000000000000001350000 \\
 13 & 12.99999999999999999941661 \\
 14 & 14.00000000000000000002521 \\
 15 & 14.99999999999999999999891
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$|x_n-n|\sim \frac 1 \pi e^{- n \pi}$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answer is satisfactory but $|\sin (\pi x)| >\epsilon$ implies $|e^{\pi x} \sin (\pi x)| >1$ whenever $x >\frac 1 {\pi} \ln (\frac 1  {\epsilon})$ which implies that $x$ is not a root of the equation  $e^{-\pi x}= \sin (\pi x)$. Of course, $|\sin (\pi x)| \leq \epsilon$ implies that $x$ is close to an integer.