# Maximize a sum of sinusoids with comensurable periods

Tags: optimization, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm writing a program that requires finding
$$\text{argmax}_\theta\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cos(k\theta+b_k),$$
where $a_k$ and $b_k$ can be any real numbers. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to take the FFT, find the maximum element, and use the result as a starting point for local optimization. This gives the right answer as long as the high-frequency elements are relatively small (otherwise I can just increase the resolution of the FFT), and the runtime is $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more on how you proceed.

Comment: @MehdiXoylu sure. Let me rewrite my formula as the sum from k=0 to N-1 of aₖcos(kθ+bₖ). Using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) this equals the real part of the sum from k=0 to N-1 of aₖe^(ibₖ)e^(kθ). This is the [DFT formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html) with fₖ=aₖe^(ibₖ) and n=-Nθ/(2π). Now you can compute my formula by computing the real part of Fₙ. The FFT lets you compute Fₙ efficiently for many values at once.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done efficiently using an eigenvalue calculation. You can transform this to a finite Fourier series by using $a_k \cos(k \theta + b_k) = a_k \cos(b_k) \cos(k \theta) - a_k \sin(b_k) \sin(k \theta)$. Then you can find all critical points, by finding the roots of the derivative. Then, one can use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370996/roots-of-a-finite-fourier-series) to find all the roots (see also [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10665-006-9087-5)). Finally, you just need to calculate the values at all these points, and pick the maximum.